# PHP: send array as form post input parameter

Tags: php, arrays

I have a pre-defined `$dogs` array. I'd like to send it with an HTML form:

```
<?php

$dogs = array("A", "B", "C");

?>

<form action="tester.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input name="dogs[]" style="display: none">

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

 <?php
 $textValue = '';
 if (sizeof($_POST) != 0) {
     try {
         $textValue = $_POST['text'];
         print_r($dogs);
         print_r('after...');

         $cats = $_POST('dogs');
         print_r($cats);
     } catch (Exception $exception)  {
        print_r($exception);
     }
 }

?>

<div>Value: <?php  echo $textValue ?></div>
```

The form submits to the same page.

I get the output:

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C ) after...
```

If I comment out the last two lines in the try statement:

```
         $textValue = $_POST['text'];
         print_r($dogs);
         print_r('after...');

         // $cats = $_POST('dogs');
         // print_r($cats);
```

I get:

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C ) after...
Value: myvalue
```

I'd like to get output:

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C ) after...Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C )
Value: myvalue
```

How should I change the code to get it?

**EDIT**:

I changed the code to

```
<?php

$dogs = array("A", "B", "C");

?>

<form action="tester.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input name="dogs[]" style="display: none">

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

 <?php
 $textValue = '';
 if (sizeof($_POST) != 0) {
     try {
         $textValue = $_POST['text'];
         print_r($dogs);
         print_r('after...');

         $cats = $_POST['dogs'];
         print_r($cats);
     } catch (Exception $exception)  {
        print_r($exception);
     }
 }

?>

<div>Value: <?php  echo $textValue ?></div>
```

now I get this output:

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C ) after...Array ( [0] => )
Value: myvalue
```

Comment: it's a typo `$_POST('dogs');` should be square braces to access values in POST

Comment: @Kevin I changed it to ` $cats = $_POST('dogs[]');` and get the same result

Comment: should be `$_POST['dogs']`

Comment: @Cositanto I tried `$_POST['dogs']` - it's the original code in my post

Comment: your code is `$_POST('dogs')`, not `$_POST['dogs']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the `$dogs` in your form, you can try:

```
<form action="tester.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text">
<?php
    foreach ($dogs as $dog) {
?>
    <input name="dogs[]" value="<?php echo $dog; ?>" style="display: none">
<?php
    }
?>
<input type="submit"/>
```

Comment: What if `$dogs` is an array of arrays? A `2D` array?

Comment: Maybe json is easier, like `<input name="dogs" value='<?php echo json_encode($dogs); ?>' >`, and use `json_decode($_POST['dogs'])` to receive it after form post.